# Compare time between consequent rows using MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

This is my table `tusers` on MySQL 5.5.1 database community version

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `tusers`;
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
| tIDUSER    | tDate      | tHour    | tID |
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
| Controneri | 2022-01-06 | 07:54:42 |   1 |
| Controneri | 2022-01-06 | 07:43:38 |   2 |
| Controneri | 2022-01-06 | 07:13:09 |   3 |
| Controneri | 2022-01-06 | 06:31:52 |   4 |
| Controneri | 2022-01-06 | 06:13:12 |   5 |
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
5 rows in set (0.13 sec)
```

I need select from the table `tusers` only these rows

```
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
| tIDUSER    | tDate      | tHour    | tID |
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
| Controneri | 2022-01-06 | 07:43:38 |   2 |
| Controneri | 2022-01-06 | 06:13:12 |   5 |
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
```

Because the other rows are repeated for the same user `Controneri` within one hour compared to the previous row.

Each user access to the web page is stored on the table tusers for date and time.
But I have to extract only the first access and exclude the repeated accesses in the time span of one hour.
On this example the user `Controneri` on January 6 he was logged in 5 times. But the valid accesses are those at `06:13:12` and `07:43:38`, because after the access at 06:13:12 there were other accesses before `07:13:12`, i.e. before the end of the hour compared to the hours `06:13:12` (`06:31:52` and `07:13:09` , rows 4 and 3).

I have tried without success.

My table structure and the `Select query` below on **[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k4nkKZVZPysoSrrhKg1iQj/2)**, which offers MySQL 5

Any suggestion?

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tusers
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tusers`;
CREATE TABLE `tusers`  (
  `tIDUSER` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tDate` date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tHour` time NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tusers
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tusers` VALUES ('Controneri', '2022-01-06', '07:54:42', 1);
INSERT INTO `tusers` VALUES ('Controneri', '2022-01-06', '07:43:38', 2);
INSERT INTO `tusers` VALUES ('Controneri', '2022-01-06', '07:13:09', 3);
INSERT INTO `tusers` VALUES ('Controneri', '2022-01-06', '06:31:52', 4);
INSERT INTO `tusers` VALUES ('Controneri', '2022-01-06', '06:13:12', 5);

SELECT
        a.tID,
        a.tDate,
        a.tHour,
        a.tIDUSER,
        TIMEDIFF( a.tHour, b.tHour ) AS tDif 
    FROM
        `tusers` a
        JOIN `tusers` b ON 
        a.tDate = b.tDate 
        AND a.tIDUSER = b.tIDUSER 
        AND a.tID > b.tID 
    WHERE
        ( TIMEDIFF( a.tHour, b.tHour ) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '01:00:00' ) 
    ORDER BY
        a.tIDUSER,
        a.tDate,
        a.tHour ASC;
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic by which you end up with those 2 records in the result set.  Can you explain more?

Comment: Why do you prefer row2 over row1 and row3

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Each user access to the web page is stored on the table `tusers` for date and time. But I have to extract only the first access and exclude the repeated accesses in the time span of one hour. On this example the user `Controneri` on January 6 he was logged in 5 times. But the valid accesses are those at `06:13:12` and `07:43:38`, because after the access at `06:13:12` there were other accesses before `07:13:12`, i.e. before the end of the hour compared to the hours `06:13:12` (`06:31:52` and `07:13:09` , rows 4 and 3)

Comment: @P.Salmon I need select row2 and row5, please see explication for TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Ok so the next row you could pick would have a minimum time of 08:43:39 and from there 09:43:40 etc.. the whole thing being based on the earliest start time

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the schema creating statements and the `SELECT` **directly** into it. It surely is nice of you to provide a fiddle, but, as this can go down, all necessary information must be included in the question **itself**, in order to make sure it still is useful in the future,

Comment: @P.Salmon exactly!

Comment: @stickybit Okay!

Comment: At this point I would say this is next to impossible using sql since the previous row is not a fixed point in time relative to the current row and changes every time you find one. In other words it's iterative and has to be reset every iteration. You could perhaps use a cursor but nobody likes them..

Comment: Recursive CTEs might solve this, but these require a lesser outdated MySQL version 8+.

Comment: @stickybit I understand, you can give me an example using CTEs and MySQL version 8+?

Comment: @P.Salmon I understand, you can give me an example using cursor?

Comment: Not ad hoc and it seems pointless to start working on it as you probably won't accept it anyways since you cannot use it on your version.

Comment: @stickybit In the hosting I have MySQL 5.5 but on the local pc I have 8.0.17 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL 5.5 you can achieve this by tracking the previous values in user variables -

```sql
SELECT tIDUSER, tDate, tHour, tID
FROM (
    SELECT
        tusers.*,
        IF(@prev_date_time IS NULL OR @prev_user <> tIDUSER OR @prev_date_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR < TIMESTAMP(tDate, tHour), @prev_date_time := TIMESTAMP(tDate, tHour), NULL) AS `show`,
        @prev_user := tIDUSER
    FROM tusers, (SELECT @prev_date_time := NULL, @prev_user := NULL) n
    ORDER BY tIDUSER ASC, tDate ASC, tHour ASC
) t
WHERE `show` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY tIDUSER ASC, tDate ASC, tHour ASC;
```

And here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a49cd2c2c3d50db656b18fe939565b60). Thanks to sticky bit as I took the liberty of "borrowing" from their [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72dcbeb05cc659bb08e3f658b642eca3).

The [MySQL 5.6 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) states -

> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
> variables is undefined.

And in [later versions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) is extended to say -

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is
> undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1
> evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.

The [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) manual also states -

> It is also possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements
> other than SET. (This functionality is deprecated in MySQL 8.0 and
> subject to removal in a subsequent release.) When making an assignment
> in this way, the assignment operator must be := and not = because the
> latter is treated as the comparison operator = in statements other
> than SET:

Despite the above warnings, this method has been widely used for many years.  Your mileage may vary.

I suspect this will perform badly with larger result sets but give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the OP in the comments, here is a query using recursive CTEs which will be available with MySQL version 8 and higher.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1
AS
(
SELECT tusers.tiduser,
       tusers.tdate,
       tusers.thour,
       tusers.tid,
       addtime(tusers.tdate, tusers.thour) AS sane_timestamp_representation,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY tusers.tiduser
                          ORDER BY addtime(tusers.tdate, tusers.thour) ASC) AS rn
       FROM tusers
),
cte2
AS
(
SELECT cte1.tiduser,
       cte1.tdate,
       cte1.thour,
       cte1.tid,
       cte1.sane_timestamp_representation,
       0 AS n
       FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT cte1.tiduser,
       cte1.tdate,
       cte1.thour,
       cte1.tid,
       cte1.sane_timestamp_representation,
       cte2.n + 1 AS n
       FROM cte2
            INNER JOIN cte1
                       ON cte2.tiduser = cte1.tiduser
                          AND cte1.sane_timestamp_representation > adddate(cte2.sane_timestamp_representation, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
),
cte3
AS
(
SELECT cte2.tiduser,
       cte2.tdate,
       cte2.thour,
       cte2.tid,
       cte2.sane_timestamp_representation,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cte2.tiduser,
                                       cte2.n
                          ORDER BY cte2.sane_timestamp_representation ASC) rn
       FROM cte2
)
SELECT cte3.tiduser,
       cte3.tdate,
       cte3.thour,
       cte3.tid
       FROM cte3
       WHERE cte3.rn = 1
       ORDER BY cte3.tiduser ASC,
                cte3.sane_timestamp_representation ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72dcbeb05cc659bb08e3f658b642eca3)

1.
In `cte1` we first and foremost unite that day and hour part of the timestamp (not the brightest idea to save them as two different columns; it'll become a mess when day boundaries have to be crossed). We also assign a `row_number()` `rn` according to the timestamp in ascending order per user. `cte1` acts  as our "base table" from now on.

2.
Now in `cte2` the recursiveness happens. As anchor we take all the rows from `cte1` where `cte1.rn = 1`. These are the records for a user with the minimum timestamp for that user. We also add some number `n`. For those initial anchor rows we set `n` to `0`. `n` will act as an indicator which rows cannot cover each other. All rows with an `n + x` for `x > 1` cannot be covered by any row with `n` (per user).

In the recursive step we join all records from `cte1` past an hour per user. Since these cannot be covered by the records already in the result set (per user), they're past an hour, we assign `n + 1` as `n` to them.

3.
`cte3` adds another `row_number()` `rn` ordering the records by the timestamp ascending per `user` and `n`. Those with an `rn` of `1` aren't covered themselves by *any* previous record for the user because all others with equal or greater `n` have greater timestamps and those with lesser `n` don't cover them as per we constructed `n`. So we can select these records from `cte3` where `rn = 1` and get our final result.

### One big fat warning though:

**The intermediate result sets will grow rapidly!** You can try to select from `cte3` without a `WHERE` clause and see for yourself. So while this shows it *can* be done *theoretically*, it might not be *practical*, even for medium sets of data. The needed resources can quickly exceed maximums.

(And well, since AFAIK SQL with recursive CTEs is Turing complete and the problem seems well computable, it was clear that it *can* be done anyway. But it still was interesting to see an example *how* it can be done, I think.)

Maybe it can be optimized. The key, I believe, is to limit the joined rows in the recursive step. We actually only need to join the oldest record past an hour, that would be the next record of interest. That would also make `cte3` and the `WHERE` in the final `SELECT` unnecessary (unless for projection to get rid of the helper columns). But I didn't find a way to do so. `LIMIT` as well as window functions aren't allowed or implemented for recursive CTEs, at least in the recursive step. But if somebody comes up with such an optimization, I'd love to see it!

Oh, and the stupid timestamp representation in two columns, which needs to be put together at first, will also render the use of indexes on the timestamps impossible. So that's another factor limiting performance here.